# Camunda Timer Intermediate Catch Event trigger by REST API

Tags: rest, camunda

I have a simpe Camunda BPMN Diagram. I add a Timer Intermediate Catch Event and set duration 23 Hours (PT23H) for testing purpose. I am trying to trigger Timer Event by Camunda REST Api during waiting postion. Tried to call rest api the following post request but gives me an error. Do you have any idea to how can i call it properly ? Thx

http://camunda-xxx/rest/message

```
{
"processInstanceId":"e984e112-27cd-11ea-8f92-0a580a800328",
"messageName":"Test"
}

{
    "type": "RestException",
    "message": "org.camunda.bpm.engine.MismatchingMessageCorrelationException: Cannot correlate message 'Test': No process definition or execution matches the parameters"
}
```

[image: Simple Camunda BPMN]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't trigger a timer via message.
Either use an event based gateway, so the process either waits for the timer or a message and then continues, or [modify the timer jobs due date](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/job/put-set-job-duedate/).